# Python string parsing

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have just started with Python and I am having trouble parsing strings. I am very much a newbie and I am just playing around with the basics for now. I thought I'd start with parsing trivial stuff like the output of `pi_info()` just to get some practice with text parsing.

Here is my script:

```
import gpiozero

boardinfo_length = None
counter = 1

boardinfo = gpiozero.pi_info()
for value in boardinfo:
 if counter != 15:
 print('[', end=' ')
 print(counter, end=' ')
 print(']', end=' ')
 print(boardinfo_length, end=' ')
 print(value)
 print()
else:
 print('[', end=' ')
 print(counter, end=' ')
 print(']', end=' ')
 split_string = value.split(":")
 for split_string_value in split_string:
 print(split_string_value)
 counter += 1
```

Here is the output:

```
[ 1 ] None a02082

[ 2 ] None 3B

[ 3 ] None 1.2

[ 4 ] None 2016Q1

[ 5 ] None BCM2837

[ 6 ] None Sony

[ 7 ] None 1024

[ 8 ] None MicroSD

[ 9 ] None 4

[ 10 ] None 1

[ 11 ] None True

[ 12 ] None True

[ 13 ] None 1

[ 14 ] None 1

[ 15 ] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "boardinfo.py", line 19, in <module>
split_string = value.split(":")
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can someone help me figure it out ...

Comment: Looks like your "value" variable in your loop is a dict object not a string. 
You should make another loop for your "value" variable since its a dictionary and print that, thats probably what you're looking for.

Comment: What are you trying to figure out?  If you're trying to parse a particular string format for a particular use, then put the problem string directly into your posting, and eliminate the superfluous code.  The error message is quite clear: `value` is a dict at that point; you tried to apply a string method.  If needed, insert useful print statements to display the data you're getting.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the last value is a dictionary, not a string. Since dicts don't have the split()-method, i probably would check the type of value first:

```
for value in boardinfo:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        # String handling
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        print("This is a dictionary: " + str(value))
    else:
        print("value has type: " + str(type(value)))
```